# What kind of heavy horses did the Manchu use?

Tags: cavalry, manchus

My friend told me that the Manchus would link 4 horses together and fight. Yufei then cut off the horses feet and won anyway.

Is this true? Where can I learn about 4 horses tied together?

Comment: Here's a forum on Chinese military tactics you might want to consult. http://www.chinahistoryforum.com/index.php?/topic/5294-chinese-cavalry-weapon/ This appears to have been an experiment with cavalry. Like Hannibal's elephants and war chariots with blades (see below), it wasn't too successful, which is probably why we haven't heard much about it since. http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/479/did-war-chariots-ever-actually-have-blades-on-the-wheel-hubs/482#482

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing a bit of research, I found nothing on the tactic of linking horses. I've read a bit of Chinese military history, and I mean no offense, but most of the stuff are lies. For example, 诸葛亮 supposedly created an perpetual motion ox to carry grain. This is impossible. Another example is 赵云 killed 100 people to save 刘备's son. A third example is that 关羽，killed numerous generals and their armies to get to 刘备。All of which are doubtful. These stories are like the story that King Arthur had a giant cross strapped to his back and killed the entire enemy army or the story that Lancelot killed a dragon. Chinese history up until maybe the Ming or Qing dynastes is cloudy and full of myths, and not very reliable.

In a more scientific perspective, it would be really hard to chop of the legs of the horses. The lances that the manchu used were just to long.
[image]

The lances next to the horses look about a horse and a half long.

Recap:

Early Chinese "history" contains lots of myths. This story you were told is probably a myth.

Comment: So horse lances are actually longer than infantry spears? Is this common?

Comment: yes, or all cavalry would be obsolete

Comment: so why does age of empires always say that spears are effective against cavalry? Oh the infantry can still puncture the horse while the cavalry lance start from way behind the horse's neck.

Comment: In the west, knights "couched" their lances meaning that they just aimed their lace at the infantry and braced it. Cavalry's power didn't come from the lance, but their ability to smash through the enemy ranks, create a hole, let the infantry exploit it, and run down the routers. In Agincourt, the English won because the French cavalry couldn't get enough momentum from their cavalry to smash enemy lines. Cavalry isn't there to be in a prolonged fight, but instead used as shock troops, meaning that all that mattered was the horse hitting and braking a hole in the enemy ranks.

Comment: Oh ya, and at times, infantry weapons were longer, and at times they were shorter, till finally, everyone used guns. Hypothesis, Antithesis, Synthesis.

Comment: what do you mean smashing enemies line? You mean hitting their shield with lances right>?

Comment: @Russell Whether there are plenty of lies or not in Chinese history, the cited examples are poor ones. They hail from San Guo Yan Yi, which as a historical novel is expected to be full of fantastical things. The history San Guo Zhi has a far more sober assessment of these men and their feats. I'd also like to see citations for the claim that pre-Ming Chinese history is unreliable. I've only seen this said of history about eras prior to Qin.

Comment: And while we're on the topic of Chinese classic novels, there's a mention of chained cavalry in Shui Hu Zhuan, a Yuan dynasty novel based on legends about a bunch of bandits during the Song. Huyan Zhuo, a Song general, leads chained cavalry to attack the bandits, who eventually defeat him with the help of Xu Ning, a master in wielding lances with hooks. I would not be surprised if some of the tactical elements or weapons mentioned did have a basis in history, even if the storyline itself is intended to be pure fiction with a slight smattering of historical backdrop.