# What weapons did Yue Fei use against the Jin Cavalry

Tags: china, cavalry, tactics, medieval-china

One of my Chinese friends said that the Jin troops rode 5 horses at once and charged as a very heavy cataphract.

Yue Fei used a special [halberd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halberd) and cut off the horses legs. The riders fell off their horses and died without having to be slaughtered further. The height of the horse and the weight of their armor along with the fall, killed the Jin riders.

Awesome. That's what I would call time saving.

Where can I learn more about this?

Comment: The military history forum may be a good place to ask some of these questions. http://www.sinodefenceforum.com/military-history/yue-fei-vs-genghis-khan-4923.html

Comment: this might be of use...

http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/857/what-kind-of-heavy-horses-did-the-manchu-use

Comment: @franklin since he asked that question too, I bet he was already aware of it...